# Inequality about functions

Tags: calculus, inequality, elliptic-equations

This inequality is on the book "Semilinear Elliptic Equations for Beginners", and is on the page 42.

$f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuos and there exists $\sigma \in (0,1)$ and $a,b >0$ such that $$|f(t)| \leq a + b|t|^{\sigma}, \\ \forall t \in \mathbb{R}$$

Thus $f$ is no longer bounded, but is allowed to grow sublinearly $(\sigma <1)$. It follows that $F$ grows at most subquadratically, in the sense that for some $a_1, b_1 > 0$, $$|F(t)| \leq a_1 + b_1|t|^{\sigma +1} \\ \forall t\in \mathbb{R}$$

Here, $F(t) = \int_{0}^{t} f(s)ds$.

My point is, together with $a_1$ why don't appears a $|t|$? Since, in my point of view, the second inequality is obtained by the integration of the first?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take $t\geq0$, the same holds for $t\leq0$.

For $t\leq1$
\begin{align}
at+\frac{b}{\sigma+1}t^{\sigma+1} &\leq a+\frac{b}{\sigma+1}t^{\sigma+1}\\
  &\leq a+\left(a+\frac{b}{\sigma+1}\right)t^{\sigma+1}
\end{align}
while, for $t\geq1$
\begin{align}
at+\frac{b}{\sigma+1}t^{\sigma+1} &\leq at^{\sigma+1}+\frac{b}{\sigma+1}t^{\sigma+1} \\
  &=\left(a+\frac{b}{\sigma+1}\right)t^{\sigma+1}\\
  &\leq a+\left(a+\frac{b}{\sigma+1}\right)t^{\sigma+1}
\end{align}
so if we take
\begin{align}
a_1 &= a\\
b_1 &= a+\frac{b}{\sigma+1}
\end{align}
the inequality is satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

It is enough to verify that, for large enough $a_1$ and $b_1$, $$at+(b/(\sigma+1))t^{\sigma+1}\le a_1+b_1 t^{\sigma+1}$$ for all large $t$.

Comment: Yes but beware not to confuse the reader: the coefficient of $|t|^{\sigma + 1}$ when computing the upper bound for $|F(t)|$ is $\frac{b}{\sigma + 1}$

Comment: Fixed it -- thanks @DodoDuQuercy

Comment: Thank you! Very good!